# How to effectively analyze a large amount of web pages with Python?

Tags: python, html, url, urllib2

So I've created a program in Python that collects post statistics off of a forum I use. It basically loops through a LONG list of URLs, opens each one with **urllib.request.urlopen**, and collects info on each post.
The problem I've run into is that this site apparently doesn't like me constantly opening a bunch of their URLs, and does what it can to prevent me from doing so. (I'm assuming this is their way of preventing spambots from flooding the site).

After this, I tried using site downloading applications like SiteSucker. But my computer doesn't have enough space for ~7,000 pages of HTML, so that doesn't work either.

What I want is to be able to safely download each page with Python, analyze its HTML, and then delete it, without the site preventing me in the process. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

requests will ignore robots.txt and possibly other bot protection, for parsing html I use Beautifulsoup after you install it you write

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

to import it. heres the website for beautifulsoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and the website for requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/